# Why `replaceState` removes `index.html` in `/basehref/index.html`

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate

I have the `/is/` set as base href and the following simple code in the `index.html` that uses `replaceState()`:

```
<base href="/is/">
<script>
    setTimeout(()=>{
        history.replaceState(null, "", "#/some");
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

The URL before the code is executed looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

However, once the code is executed the `index.html` is gone and the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/is/#/some
```

I expected it to look like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/is/index.html#/some
```

Why is `index.html` gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<base>` tag establishes the document base URL. That serves as the reference point for all relative URLs in APIs like the History API. That's kind-of the whole point of `<base>`.

The "current" URL is called the "fallback base URL" in the W3C specs, and it only comes into play when there's no `<base>` tag with a specified `href` value.

So the answer is basically that that's the way things work.

Comment: [Here's a W3C link.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/urls.html#document-base-url)

Comment: thanks, so what you're saying the cause is `base href`, not `replaceState`?

Comment: Right, you've put a `<base>` tag in the document so the browser thinks that that's what you want it to do. Oddly I don't think I've ever used a `<base>` tag in many years of web programming.

Comment: thanks, it's interesting though that `base href` is applied and `index.html` is removed only on `replaceState`, not when a page is loaded